# WP Pagination not looping through posts

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to fix up a child theme on top of WP Pro Real Estate 3 that someone else created. Elsewhere in  the theme, there is a different content navigation happening. I have tried hooking up a plugin for pagination, and it also wouldn't loop through posts. The URL updates, but the 10 posts showing are always the same.

Here is the code for the page. Where should I look first to figure out what might be causing the issue?

```
        <?php global $ct_options;
            if($ct_options['ct_layout'] == 'left-sidebar') {
            get_sidebar();
        } ?>

        <section id="blog" class="ten columns marT20 left">
        <h2> Blog </h2>

        <?php query_posts( 'cat=-39' ); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('left clear'); ?>>                        

                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                                    } ?>

                    <h2 class="entry-title marB18"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <br/>
                    <?php ct_read_more_link(); ?>
                    <!-- <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more" />Read More</a> -->

                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">' . __('Pages:', 'responsive'), 'after' => '</div>')); ?>
                </article>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

              <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);

 } ?>     

        </section>


        <div class="sidebar six columns marT20 left">
            <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Blog') ) :else: endif; ?>

            <div id="sidebar-inner">
                <aside class="widget widget_text left" id="about-nic-nav"><h4>About Nicaragua</h4>
                    <div class="textwidget">
                    <?php query_posts( 'cat=39' ); ?>
                    <ul>
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </aside>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as it is called **after** The Loop, I'd suggest that the `pagination()` function from your plugin only adds page numbers. It does not actually setup your query for pagination.

To do this you need to ensure that you include the `paged` parameter in your query.

For example, to show 5 published posts per page in date order, include this **before** The Loop -

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => DESC,
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish'
);
query_posts($args);
```

Check out the [Pagination Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) section of the [WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more information.

Also, check out the [Codex for The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) if you are unsure of what that is.

**Additional Information**

As an aside, I notice in your code that you use The Loop twice. There are many occasions when this is necessary, however on both occasions yours appears to be the same, so therefore there is no need to recall `query_posts()`. Instead, at the end of the frist run of The Loop call `wp_reset_query()` (it's a good habit to always us that one anyway), which will set the pointer back to the start of The Loop, and will save you time as you will not have to query the database again.

If however you do require The Loops to output different Posts you should use `new WP_Query()` instead (to be honest, I'd recommend always using that as opposed to `the_query()`, as it's easier to customise using hooks if required). For example -

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => 10,
    'post_status' => 'scheduled'
);
$scheduled_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if($scheduled_posts->have_posts()) : while($scheduled_posts->have_posts()) : $scheduled_posts->the_post();
?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
            <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </div>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks you! I have seen that args block before, but I must have been missing a piece of it to not make it work. It works now though! Cheers!